# Curl error : could not resolve host

Tags: curl, flurry

I am trying to download flurry analytics exception logs using CURL. I am following the guide in [this](http://chomptech.wordpress.com/2010/03/22/getting-access-to-your-flurry-exception-logs/) page.

When i try to do the following in command prompt, curl says **curl: (6) Could not resolve host: \; Host not found**

```
curl --cookie ./flurry.jar \ http://dev.flurry.com/exceptionLogsCsv.do?projectID=49999&versionCut=versionsAll&intervalCut=allTime&direction=1&offset=23&pageSize=15 \ --output "exception#1.csv"
```

I have spent significant time on this but still havent managed to get it to download the data. Please could any one help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove those backslashes. They only used for multi-line command (as shown on that guide you referenced).

```
curl --cookie ./flurry.jar http://dev.flurry.com/exceptionLogsCsv.do?projectID=49999&versionCut=versionsAll&intervalCut=allTime&direction=1&offset=23&pageSize=15 --output "exception#1.csv"
```

Comment: thanks, it doesnt show the could not resolve host error now. but it says 'versionCut' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. and the same message for all the other parameters as well. Is this not the right way to pass the parameters?

Comment: Try to put the address (`http://...pageSize=15`) inside double-quotes. The shell thinks that the ampersand (&) in the address is part of the shell command.